# mongoose Schema to sequelize model

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sequelize.js

I made one app with `mongodb` (mongoose as ODM) but now I want to work with `MySQL` (work obligation) so I took `Sequelize` module for that, but I really don't understand how to convert my userSchema to user model with all its méthodes (I'm working with `passportJs` for authentication, so I have some methods that I'm using for example setpassword ...)

Here my userSchema (mongoose) that works perfectly.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var validator = require('node-mongoose-validator');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 50
    },
    mail: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 50,
      index: {
        unique: true
      }
    },
    hash: String,
    salt: String,
    {
      collection: "user"
    }
);

userSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password) {
  this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
  var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
  return this.hash === hash;
};

userSchema.methods.generateJwt = function() {
  var expiry = new Date();
  expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 7);

  return jwt.sign({
    _id: this._id,
    mail: this.mail,
    name: this.name,
    exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000),
  }, process.env.JWT_SECRET); // secret code from .env
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

and here what I've tried with sequelize:

```
 var crypto = require('crypto');
    var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
      name: Sequelize.STRING,
      mail: Sequelize.STRING,
      hash: Sequelize.STRING,
      salt: Sequelize.STRING


    });

    User.methods.setPassword = function(password) {
      this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
      this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
    };

    User.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
      var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
      return this.hash === hash;
    };

    User.methods.generateJwt = function() {
      var expiry = new Date();
      expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 7);

      return jwt.sign({
        _id: this._id,
        mail: this.mail,
        name: this.name,
        exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000),
      }, process.env.JWT_SECRET); // DO NOT KEEP YOUR SECRET IN THE CODE!
    };


module.exports = User;
```

I did not test that because I need to develop one other part, but I need to know that do you think about that, I feel that its full of errors

Thank you in advance

Comment: Very good question, yet no answers :(

Comment: Can you get Mongoose to show you the generated SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will focus on defining a model with instance methods, some logic specific to passportjs and mongoose you might have to implement differently.

There are [2 ways](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#model-definition) to define a model.

1. With [`sequelize.define`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#using--a-href-----class-lib-sequelize-js-sequelize-html-instance-method-define---code-sequelize-define--code---a--) like the way you implemented, you can attach instance methods using `User.prototype.yourMethod` since `User` [is a ES6 class](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#taking-advantage-of-models-being-classes)

```js
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  mail: DataTypes.STRING,
  hash: DataTypes.STRING,
  salt: DataTypes.STRING,
/* ... */
});

User.prototype.validPassword = function(password) {
  var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
  return this.hash === hash;
};

/*
If you want an equivalent of User.statics.yourStaticMethod = function() {}
or User.static('yourstaticmethod', function() {})
You can use the following
*/

User.yourStaticMethod = function() {};
```

2. You can also [extend `Model`](http://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#extending--a-href-----class-lib-model-js-model-html--model--a-)

```
class User extends Model {
  static yourStaticMethod() {} // in mongoose equivalent to User.statics.yourStaticMethod = function() {}
  validPassword(password) {
    var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
  }
};

User.init({
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  mail: DataTypes.STRING,
  hash: DataTypes.STRING,
  salt: DataTypes.STRING,
/* ... */
}, {
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'user'
});
```